# How to get the age of someones account? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

To prevent new accounts from using a certain command, how could I get the age of a users account (or creation date) when they type a message.

```
client.get_user(account_date)

if account_date < 14:
   print('Your account must be older than 14 days to use this command')
else:
   print('Your account can use this command')
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a User object from either ctx with `ctx.author` or from a message with `message.author`.

Then on the User object you can call `created_at`.

So for example to get account of current user

```
@bot.command()
async def CreatedAccountAt(self,ctx):
   await ctx.send(ctx.author.created_at)
```

or to get a user created date by ID

```
@bot.command()
async def CreatedAccountAt(ctx, userId: int):
    user =  bot.get_user(userId)
    await ctx.send(user.created_at)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.created_at