# How can I know when a user joined Discord in Discord.py (Discord join date, not server)

Tags: python, discord.py

I know that to know when a user joined your server, you can:
`member.joined_at`
will work out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the age of someones account? Discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611157/how-to-get-the-age-of-someones-account-discord-py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`User.created_at`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.created_at):

```
@client.command()
async def userinfo(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    created_at = member.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y")
    await ctx.send(created_at)
```